# Source of Ruby benchmark irregularites

Tags: ruby, performance, benchmarking

Running this code:

```
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("1+1") {15_000_000.times {1+1}}
  x.report("1+1") {15_000_000.times {1+1}}
  x.report("1+1") {15_000_000.times {1+1}}
  x.report("1+1") {15_000_000.times {1+1}}
  x.report("1+1") {15_000_000.times {1+1}}
end
```

Outputs these results:

```
       user     system      total        real
1+1  2.188000   0.000000   2.188000 (  2.250000)
1+1  2.250000   0.000000   2.250000 (  2.265625)
1+1  2.234000   0.000000   2.234000 (  2.250000)
1+1  2.203000   0.000000   2.203000 (  2.250000)
1+1  2.266000   0.000000   2.266000 (  2.281250)
```

Guessing the variation is a result of the system environment, but wanted to confirm this is the case.

Comment: "Guessing the variation is a result of the system environment", you are right.

Comment: @LBg: Thanks, feel free to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Guessing the variation is a result of the system environment", you are right.

Benchmarks can't be precise all time. You don't have a perfect regular machine to run something always in the same time. Take two numbers from benchmark as the same if they were too near, as in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using `eval` to partially unroll the loop, and although it made it faster, it made the execution time less consistent!

```
$VERBOSE &&= false # You do not want 15 thousand "warning: useless use of + in void context" warnings
# large_number = 15_000_000 # Too large! Caused eval to take too long, so I gave up
somewhat_large_number = 15_000
unrolled = "def do_addition\n" + ("1+1\n" * somewhat_large_number) + "end\n" ; nil
eval(unrolled)

require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report("1+1 partially unrolled") { i = 0; while i < 1000; do_addition; i += 1; end}
  x.report("1+1 partially unrolled") { i = 0; while i < 1000; do_addition; i += 1; end}
  x.report("1+1 partially unrolled") { i = 0; while i < 1000; do_addition; i += 1; end}
  x.report("1+1 partially unrolled") { i = 0; while i < 1000; do_addition; i += 1; end}
  x.report("1+1 partially unrolled") { i = 0; while i < 1000; do_addition; i += 1; end}
  x.report("1+1 partially unrolled") { i = 0; while i < 1000; do_addition; i += 1; end}
  x.report("1+1 partially unrolled") { i = 0; while i < 1000; do_addition; i += 1; end}
  x.report("1+1 partially unrolled") { i = 0; while i < 1000; do_addition; i += 1; end}
  x.report("1+1 partially unrolled") { i = 0; while i < 1000; do_addition; i += 1; end}
  x.report("1+1 partially unrolled") { i = 0; while i < 1000; do_addition; i += 1; end}
end
```

gave me

```
      user     system      total        real
1+1 partially unrolled  0.750000   0.000000   0.750000 (  0.765586)
1+1 partially unrolled  0.765000   0.000000   0.765000 (  0.765586)
1+1 partially unrolled  0.688000   0.000000   0.688000 (  0.703089)
1+1 partially unrolled  0.797000   0.000000   0.797000 (  0.796834)
1+1 partially unrolled  0.750000   0.000000   0.750000 (  0.749962)
1+1 partially unrolled  0.781000   0.000000   0.781000 (  0.781210)
1+1 partially unrolled  0.719000   0.000000   0.719000 (  0.718713)
1+1 partially unrolled  0.750000   0.000000   0.750000 (  0.749962)
1+1 partially unrolled  0.765000   0.000000   0.765000 (  0.765585)
1+1 partially unrolled  0.781000   0.000000   0.781000 (  0.781210)
```

For the purpose of comparison, your benchmark on my computer gave

```
      user     system      total        real
1+1  2.406000   0.000000   2.406000 (  2.406497)
1+1  2.407000   0.000000   2.407000 (  2.484629)
1+1  2.500000   0.000000   2.500000 (  2.734655)
1+1  2.515000   0.000000   2.515000 (  2.765908)
1+1  2.703000   0.000000   2.703000 (  4.391075)
```

(real time varied in the last line, but not user or total)

Comment: @Grimm: I'm confused, the change you made appears slower than the code posted. Meaning your code was so slow it couldn't process adding "1+1" 15 million times. There's a huge differ between the stablity and runtime of the code I posted, and the code you posted. Only thing your proves to me really is how more unstable benchmarking can be. Am I missing something? Guess the main thing I don't get is how your answer relates to my question. Realize you took the time to think over the problem, I just feel like I'm missing your point. Thanks!

Comment: @blunders: I could not make `do_addition` consist of 15 million additions, so instead I made it consist of 15 thousand additions and called it a thousand times. 15_000 * 1000 == 15_000_000.

Comment: @Grimm: What is the question your answer is addressing? The question I posted was basically would someone please confirm that benchmark results are only as stable as the environment they're run in. The code was only provided as a proof of concept that was easy to read, and see that the results were unstable.